# JQuery Image Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello i am looking for a simple full page image carousel that just pulls images and slides them across the screen without stoping unless hovered i have one that currently works but once it has ran through the sequence its almost as if it is throwing an image on top of each other. i will show you what i have so far

this is my sizing script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reSize($target){
        $target.css('width', $(window).width()+'px');
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).bind('resize', reSize($('#wn')));
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    });
</script>
```

The actual script:

```
var DYN_WEB = DYN_WEB || {};


DYN_WEB.Event=(function(Ev){Ev.add=document.addEventListener?function(obj,etype,fp,cap){cap=cap||false;obj.addEventListener(etype,fp,cap);}:function(obj,etype,fp){obj.attachEvent('on'+etype,fp);};Ev.remove=document.removeEventListener?function(obj,etype,fp,cap){cap=cap||false;obj.removeEventListener(etype,fp,cap);}:function(obj,etype,fp){obj.detachEvent('on'+etype,fp);};Ev.DOMit=function(e){e=e?e:window.event;if(!e.target){e.target=e.srcElement;}if(!e.preventDefault){e.preventDefault=function(){e.returnValue=false;return false;};}if(!e.stopPropagation){e.stopPropagation=function(){e.cancelBubble=true;};}return e;};Ev.getTarget=function(e){e=Ev.DOMit(e);var tgt=e.target;if(tgt.nodeType!==1){tgt=tgt.parentNode;}return tgt;};Ev.domReady=(function(){var funcs=[];var ready=false;function handler(e){if(ready){return;}if(e.type==="readystatechange"&&document.readyState!=="complete"){return;}for(var i=0,len=funcs.length;i<len;i++){funcs[i].call(document);}ready=true;funcs=[];}if(document.addEventListener){document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",handler,false);document.addEventListener("readystatechange",handler,false);window.addEventListener("load",handler,false);}else if(document.attachEvent){document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",handler);window.attachEvent("onload",handler);}return function whenReady(f){if(ready){f.call(document);}else{funcs.push(f);}};})();return Ev;})(DYN_WEB.Event||{});

DYN_WEB.Util=(function(Ut){var Ev=DYN_WEB.Event;Ut.$=function(id){return document.getElementById(id);};Ut.augment=function(Obj1,Obj2){var prop;for(prop in Obj2){if(Obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop)&&!Obj1[prop]){Obj1[prop]=Obj2[prop];}}};Ut.contained=function(oNode,oCont){if(!oNode){return false;}while((oNode=oNode.parentNode)){if(oNode===oCont){return true;}}return false;};Ut.mouseleave=function(e,oNode){e=Ev.DOMit(e);var toEl=e.relatedTarget?e.relatedTarget:e.toElement?e.toElement:null;if(oNode!==toEl&&!Ut.contained(toEl,oNode)){return true;}return false;};Ut.getLayerOffsets=function(el,oCont){var left=0,top=0;if(Ut.contained(el,oCont)){do{left+=el.offsetLeft;top+=el.offsetTop;}while(((el=el.offsetParent)!==oCont));}return{x:left,y:top};};return Ut;})(DYN_WEB.Util||{});

DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div=(function(){var Ut=DYN_WEB.Util;function SDiv(wnId,lyrId){this.id=wnId;SDiv.col[this.id]=this;SDiv.ids[SDiv.ids.length]=this.id;this.load(lyrId);}SDiv.col={};SDiv.ids=[];SDiv.isSupported=function(){return!!(document.getElementById&&(document.addEventListener||document.attachEvent));};SDiv.prototype={load:function(lyrId){var lyr;if(this.lyrId){lyr=Ut.$(this.lyrId);lyr.style.visibility="hidden";}this.lyr=lyr=Ut.$(lyrId);this.lyr.style.position='absolute';this.lyrId=lyrId;this.y=0;this.x=0;this.shiftTo(0,0);this.getDims();lyr.style.visibility="visible";this.ready=true;this.on_load();},shiftTo:function(x,y){if(this.lyr&&!isNaN(x)&&!isNaN(y)){this.x=x;this.y=y;this.lyr.style.left=Math.round(x)+"px";this.lyr.style.top=Math.round(y)+"px";}},getDims:function(){var wndo=Ut.$(this.id);var lyr=Ut.$(this.lyrId);this.lyrWd=lyr.offsetWidth;this.lyrHt=lyr.offsetHeight;this.wnWd=wndo.offsetWidth;this.wnHt=wndo.offsetHeight;var w=this.lyrWd-this.wnWd;var h=this.lyrHt-this.wnHt;this.maxX=(w>0)?w:0;this.maxY=(h>0)?h:0;},on_load:function(){},on_scroll:function(){},on_scroll_start:function(){},on_scroll_stop:function(){},on_scroll_end:function(){},clearTimer:function(){clearInterval(this.timerId);this.timerId=0;}};return SDiv;})();

(function(){var Ut=DYN_WEB.Util,SDiv=DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div;SDiv.defaultSpeed=100;var Smooth_Scroll={initScrollVals:function(deg,speed){if(!this.ready){return;}this.clearTimer();this.speed=speed||SDiv.defaultSpeed;this.fx=(deg===0)?-1:(deg===180)?1:0;this.fy=(deg===90)?1:(deg===270)?-1:0;this.endX=(deg===90||deg===270)?this.x:(deg===0)?-this.maxX:0;this.endY=(deg===0||deg===180)?this.y:(deg===90)?0:-this.maxY;this.lyr=Ut.$(this.lyrId);this.lastTime=new Date().getTime();this.on_scroll_start(this.x,this.y);var self=this;self.timerId=setInterval(function(){self.scroll();},10);},scroll:function(){var now=new Date().getTime();var d=(now-this.lastTime)/1000*this.speed;if(d>0){var x=this.x+(this.fx*d);var y=this.y+(this.fy*d);if((this.fx===-1&&x>-this.maxX)||(this.fx===1&&x<0)||(this.fy===-1&&y>-this.maxY)||(this.fy===1&&y<0)){this.lastTime=now;this.shiftTo(x,y);this.on_scroll(x,y);}else{this.clearTimer();this.shiftTo(this.endX,this.endY);this.on_scroll(this.endX,this.endY);this.on_scroll_end(this.endX,this.endY);}}},ceaseScroll:function(){if(!this.ready){return;}this.clearTimer();this.on_scroll_stop(this.x,this.y);}};Ut.augment(SDiv.prototype,Smooth_Scroll);})();

(function(){var Ev=DYN_WEB.Event,Ut=DYN_WEB.Util,SDiv=DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div;var Smooth_Auto_Scroll={makeSmoothAuto:function(opts){var axis=opts.axis||'h',dir=(axis==='v')?270:0,wn=Ut.$(this.id),self=this;this.speed=opts.speed||SDiv.defaultSpeed;if(opts.bRepeat&&opts.repeatId){var pos=Ut.getLayerOffsets(Ut.$(opts.repeatId),Ut.$(this.id));this.on_scroll=function(){var backToStart;if(axis==='v'&&Math.round(this.y)<=-pos.y){backToStart=true;}else if(axis==='h'&&Math.round(this.x)<=-pos.x){backToStart=true;}if(backToStart){this.shiftTo(0,0);this.initScrollVals(dir,this.speed);}};}if(opts.bPauseResume){Ev.add(wn,'mouseover',function(){self.ceaseScroll();});Ev.add(wn,'mouseout',function(e){self.checkMouseout(e,self.id,dir);});}this.initScrollVals(dir,this.speed);},checkMouseout:function(e,wnId,dir){var self=SDiv.col[wnId];if(Ut.mouseleave(e,Ut.$(wnId))){self.initScrollVals(dir,self.speed);}}};Ut.augment(SDiv.prototype,Smooth_Auto_Scroll);})();
```

and more script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if ( DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div.isSupported() ) {

        DYN_WEB.Event.domReady( function() {

            var wndo = new DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div('wn', 'lyr1');
            wndo.makeSmoothAuto( {axis:'h', bRepeat:true, repeatId:'rpt1', speed:85, bPauseResume:true} );
        });
    }

    </script>
```

the css:

```
div#wn { 
    position:relative; 
    left:0;
    height:245px; 
    border: 4px;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

div#inner1{
    white-space:nowrap;
    }
div#inner1 img {
    margin:0 2px 0 2px;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #0000CC;
    }
#slider{
    padding:4px 4px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#sliderCont{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="sliderCont" class="container">
             <div id="wn">
                <div id="lyr1">
                    <div id="inner1">
                        <?php
        if($frontPage=="yes"){
            echo "<img src='/~Damian/home/images/caps.jpg' width='320' height='240'/>";


                                    // generates random images for slideshow
                                            $dir = "images/"; //set path to images
                                            $thumbDir = "images/"; //set path to image thumbnails
                                            $numberToDisplay = 17; //number of images to display

                                            if ($handle = opendir($thumbDir)) { 
                                                while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                                                    if (!preg_match('/^\.+$/', $file) and 
                                                       preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.JPG|\.jpeg|\.JPEG)$/', $file)){
                                                        $files[] = $file;
                                                       }
                                                }
                                                closedir($handle); 
                                            }
                                            $i = 0;
                                            $images = array_rand(array_flip($files), $numberToDisplay);
                                            while ($i < $numberToDisplay){
                                                echo "<img src='$thumbDir/$images[$i]' width='320' height='240' alt='random image' />";
                                            $i++;
                                            }


                            echo "<img id='rpt1' src='/~Damian/home/images/caps.jpg' width='320' height='240'/>";
                            // generates random images for slideshow
                                            $dir = "images/"; //set path to images
                                            $thumbDir = "images/"; //set path to image thumbnails
                                            $numberToDisplay = 17; //number of images to display

                                            if ($handle = opendir($thumbDir)) { 
                                                while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                                                    if (!preg_match('/^\.+$/', $file) and 
                                                       preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.JPG|\.jpeg|\.JPEG)$/', $file)){
                                                        $files[] = $file;
                                                       }
                                                }
                                                closedir($handle); 
                                            }
                                            $i = 0;
                                            $images = array_rand(array_flip($files), $numberToDisplay);
                                            while ($i < $numberToDisplay){
                                                echo "<img src='$thumbDir/$images[$i]' width='320' height='240' alt='random image' />";
                                            $i++;
                                            }
            }
            else{
                echo "<img src='/~Damian/home/images/caps.jpg' width='320' height='240'/>";


                                    // generates random images for slideshow
                                            $dir = "../images/"; //set path to images
                                            $thumbDir = "../images/"; //set path to image thumbnails
                                            $numberToDisplay = 17; //number of images to display

                                            if ($handle = opendir($thumbDir)) { 
                                                while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                                                    if (!preg_match('/^\.+$/', $file) and 
                                                       preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.JPG|\.jpeg|\.JPEG)$/', $file)){
                                                        $files[] = $file;
                                                       }
                                                }
                                                closedir($handle); 
                                            }
                                            $i = 0;
                                            $images = array_rand(array_flip($files), $numberToDisplay);
                                            while ($i < $numberToDisplay){
                                                echo "<img src='$thumbDir/$images[$i]' width='320' height='240' alt='random image' />";
                                            $i++;
                                            }


                            echo "<img id='rpt1' src='/~Damian/home/images/caps.jpg' width='320' height='240'/>";
                            // generates random images for slideshow
                                            $dir = "../images/"; //set path to images
                                            $thumbDir = "../images/"; //set path to image thumbnails
                                            $numberToDisplay = 17; //number of images to display

                                            if ($handle = opendir($thumbDir)) { 
                                                while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                                                    if (!preg_match('/^\.+$/', $file) and 
                                                       preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.JPG|\.jpeg|\.JPEG)$/', $file)){
                                                        $files[] = $file;
                                                       }
                                                }
                                                closedir($handle); 
                                            }
                                            $i = 0;
                                            $images = array_rand(array_flip($files), $numberToDisplay);
                                            while ($i < $numberToDisplay){
                                                echo "<img src='$thumbDir/$images[$i]' width='320' height='240' alt='random image' />";
                                            $i++;
                                            }


            }


                            ?>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>  <!-- end wn div -->
        </div>
```

Comment: Please make a http://jsfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using jQuery only for binding things. Have you tried looking jQuery plugins for carousel ?

You can save a lot of trouble and work once you're dealing with it, for instance: http://www.jssor.com/development/index.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Give a try to jcarousel (http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/), it's really easy to use, and it does the job.

Comment: I took a look and this is exactly what i am looking for http://www.jssor.com/demos/scrolling-logo-thumbnail-slider.html  but it gives no code for this specific carousel

Comment: did a little reserch and have the jssor.com/demos/scrolling-logo-thumbnail-slider.html working like a dream